# System of ODE - fundamental matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not sure how a definite integral is used in this context. Say I have the system $\vec{z}^{'}(t) = A\vec{z}(t) +\vec{a}(t)$ where A is a matrix.
Then the inhomogeneous solution is generally $\vec{z_p}=\Phi(t)\int \Phi^{-1}(t)\vec{a}(t)dt$ where $\Phi$ is the fundamental matrix. I can find the integration constant using given initial values. But I sometimes see it written like this:
$\vec{z_p}=\Phi(t)\int_{t_{0}}^t \Phi^{-1}(m)\vec{a}(m)dm$ Where m is some dummy variable and $t_0$ is that of the initial condition. How does that generally get us the same result as the indefinite integral?

Answer (score 1):

Analogous to the usual calculus result, for a vector-valued function the definite integral
$\int_{t_0}^t \vec{F}(m) \; dm$ is one antiderivative of $\vec{F}(t)$, and the general antiderivative is $\int_{t_0}^t \vec{F}(m)\; dm + \vec{c}$ where $\vec{c}$ is an arbitrary vector.  So your $\vec{z}_p$ is one particular solution of the differential equation (that subscript $p$ stands for "particular"), and the general solution is
$\vec{z}_p(t) + \Phi(t) \vec{c}$.